# What can happen if I do not disclose a conduct violation from grad school when applying to a new grad school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, academic-history, graduation, drugs

I just received a conduct violation at my current grad school for a failed drug test when trying to attain a new internship. I had been taking CBD gummies that caused me to fail. I now have been withdrawn and can't be reinstated till this time next year. I would have to start mid-year with a whole new group of people because this is the "earliest" they can place me at a site in order to complete the necessary hours for graduation. Along with this, they would disclose this drug test failure to every potential internship site and I could be turned away. As well as also disclosing the drug test failure when I apply for licensure to the board who could potentially reject me.

If I were to apply to other schools and just start over would I have to disclose that I went to this school at all? Can I potentially just put this all in the past and start over somewhere else so this doesn't hang over my head for my entire career? Could I potentially face even bigger problems if another program finds out I didn't disclose my entire academic record?

Comment: What field, generally speaking? Medicine?

Comment: Mental Health Counseling/ Art Therapy

Comment: What country? .

Comment: You get drug tested in grad school? What country is this? It seems out of this world to me that a school would have any business in your personal life, e.g. what drugs you take on your own time.

Comment: @Chris_abc The drug testing was for an internship, not the university itself.

Comment: @Chris_abc It is common in medical/life sciences when the student is under the umbrella of the university hospital. It flows down from state and federal regulations regarding medical workers and access to controlled substances. These students are also subject to background checks, mandatory vaccinations, communicable disease screens, wearing a uniform and badges, etc. as one would expect from a hospital worker.

Answer (score 2):

To some extend the answer is obvious: using drugs and lying (by omission) with the purpose of hiding it is two offenses. Two offenses is more serious than one offense.

Think about scandals: the original "crime" is often not so bad, but it is the act of hiding it that makes a scandal a scandal.